How to select partial text using SwiftUI UITextView inside a ScrollView?
We are working on a SwiftUI-based project where we need the ability for users to select and copy specific parts of the text, rather than copying the entire text, as provided by SwiftUI's .textSelection() modifier. Our current approach is using UITextView within a UIViewRepresentable.
Our Requirements:

Partial text selection: Users should be able to select a portion of the text and copy it.
The text view should not scroll and should render correctly with proper height and width.
We are working with attributed text within the UITextView.

The Issue:
We are embedding this UITextView inside a ScrollView that contains other views. However, we are encountering the following issues:

When we disable scrolling for the UITextView, the text expands beyond the available width, disrupting the layout of other views.
When scrolling is enabled, the UITextView renders with a very small height, causing it to be incomplete and not fully visible.

Is there a way to properly fit the UITextView within the SwiftUI layout (especially inside a ScrollView) while disabling scrolling and maintaining text selection functionality?
The code is the following:
struct TextView: UIViewRepresentable {
     var text: AttributedString
     var textStyle: UIFont
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView()
        
        // set font property
        textView.font = textStyle
        textView.isSelectable = true
        
        // enable user interaction
        textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        // set is editable to false
        // to prevent user editing the text view
        // or avoid showing any cursor
        textView.isEditable = false
        
        // disable scroll to avoid the text view to be shown
        // inside a scrollable view
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        
        // tracks the height of the view based on content inside it
        textView.textContainer.heightTracksTextView = true
        return textView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        // set attributed text to ui text view
        uiView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(text)
        // set font
        uiView.font = textStyle
    }
}

Thank you!
Please click on the link for the issue image -
Cropped Text Image

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
